# Creating dictionary using the data of planets

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a bunch of details about of the planets in the solar system. I am supposed to make a dictionary in Python out of it. For each planet, I have its radius, distance from sun, number of moons, if a atmospheres exists, name of moons, if it's a gas planets and so on.

For example, here is the data for Mercury:

```
Mercury
    Radius - 2,439.7 km
    Distance from the sun - 58 million km
    Moons - none
    Atmosphere? True
    Gas planet? False
```

How would I use all this data to create a dictionary?

So far I have:

```
radius = {} #radius of planets
radius['Mercury'] = 2439.7
radius['Venus'] = 6051.8
radius['Earth'] = 6371.0
radius['Mars'] = 3,396.2
radius['Jupiter'] = 69,911
radius['Saturn'] = 60,268
radius['Uranus'] = 25,559
radius['Neptune'] = 24,764

distance = {} # distance from sun
distance['Mercury'] = 58000000
distance['Venus'] = 108000000
```

i was planning of continuing this to create a dictionary for all the data that I have so that I would have different sections for each different type of data.

However, I don't if this is the right way to do it. Could somebody tell me if I am going in the right direction? If not, how would I fix it?

Comment: (a) You can't use commas in numbers in Python.  (b) You know you can describe a dictionary with a single expression like `{"Mercury": 2439.7, "Venus": 6051.8, ...}` and not bother with setting each value individually, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably much easier to make a dictionary of planets, each member of which contains a dictionary of that planet's properties. You can also save yourself some effort and avoid repetition by using the dictionary literal syntax.

Doing it as suggested above looks something like this:

```
planets = {
  'Mercury': {
    'radius': 2439.7,
    'distance': 58000000
    'moons': []
    # etc...
  },
  'Venus': {
    'radius': 6051.8,
    'distance': 108000000,
    'moons': []
    # etc...
  },
  'Earth': {
    'radius': 6371.0,
    'distance': 150000000,
    'moons': ['Luna']
     # etc...
  }
  # etc...
}
```

Comment: if a planet had moons how would you put its name in the dictionary

Comment: @user2994135: I've updated my answer to demonstrate. Planets with moons can have a list of moon names as a 'moons' member, and planets without moons (i.e. Mercury and Venus) have an empty list (or you could alternatively omit the member in those cases).

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be better to structure your data so it looks like this:

```
planets = {
    "mercury": {
        "radius": 2439.7,
        "distance": 58000000,
        # etc
    },
    "venus": {
        "radius": 6051.8,
        "distance": 108000000,
        # etc
    },
    #etc
}
```

That way, we only need a single variable, and can automatically keep all the data related to a single planet in one place.

Then, if you want to obtain all the distances of a planet (for example), you can construct another temporary dictionary by using either list or dictionary comprehensions:

```
distances = {planet: planets[planet]['distance'] for planet in planets}
```

Comment: That last code snippet won't work.  It needs to be `{planet: planets[planet]['distance'] for ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

I would design the dictionary so that the key is the planet name, and the values are another dictionary, the keys of which are the properties.

You would access it as follows:

```
mercury_radius = planet["mercury"]["radius"]
```

And declare it as follows:

```
planets = {
    "mercury" : {
        "radius" : 2439.7,
        "distance_sun" : 58000000,
        "moons" : 0,
        "atmosphere" : True,
        "gas_planet" : False
        }
}
```